# Can I have a Guice @Provides method in a class that doesn't extends AbstractModule?

Tags: guice

My quetion is simple Can I make a @Provides method in a class which doesnt extends AbstractModule?

```
 @Provides
    public int someMethod() {
        return someValue;
    }
```

Can I have something like this in a class which doesnt extends AbstractModule, or it should always in a guicemodule class?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, you can, but your class has to implement `Module`.

Technically, everything is a `Module`, so Guice has to identify it as such. Guice expects to run `configure(Binder)` on it.

This is how you do it:

```
public class MyModule implements Module { // See? No AbstractModule
  @Provides
  public int someMethod() {
    return someValue;
  }
  @Override public void configure(Binder binder) {}
}
```

If you just want a dummy class without any implementation requirement to store all your modules, then you're currently out of luck as it's not possible.

However since Guice 4.1, you can write the following without having to implement `configure(Binder)`, which is not so bad:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Provides
  public int someMethod() {
    return someValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: But thats what I dont wanna do !!
How can I have a @provides method for a object which is in some other class (a class which dont extend abstract module)

Comment: @AdityaVerma I updated the answer. You don't have to extend `AbstractModule`, but you have to implement `Module`.